# When should I use C++ instead of SQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, data-analysis

I am a C++ programmer who occasionally uses MySQL to work with databases, but my SQL knowledge is rather limited. However I am surely willing to change that.

At the moment I am trying to do analysis(!) on the data I have in my database solely with SQL queries. But I am about to give up, and instead import the data to C++ and do the analysis with C++ code.

I have discussed this with my colleagues, and they also push me to use C++, saying that SQL is not meant for complex analysis but mainly for importing (from the existing tables) and exporting (to new tables) data, and a little bit more such as merging data to - e.g. - joined tables.

Can somebody help me drawing a line? So I know when to switch to C++? Of course performance is also an issue.

What are indications that things get to complex in SQL? Or maybe I just take the wrong approach with designing the queries. Then where can I find tutorials, books, ... to take a better approach?

I hope this is not too vague. I am really a bit lost.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I see that people want this question to be closed. I guess because it's too vague and leads to "opinions", rather than "facts". I understand. However I must say the answers helped me a lot, and looking at them, I see that good reasoning from experience programmers changes "opinion" into "fact". Also a remarkable number of people rated my question +1, which indicates that there is more people out there that like to see answers to this "problem".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SQL excels at analyzing **large sets of relational data**.

The place to draw the line is the scale of your analysis.

If you analyze **individual records** one at a time, do it in your application.

If you analyze **large sets of records** as a unit, SQL is definitely the best tool for that job.

Row-by-row analysis is not something SQL is designed or optimized for very well.  But, if you want to know something about a million-row group of data, do it in the database.

Comment: what is row-by-row *analysis*? manual labor? then SQL becomes pretty efficient tool in picking those rows (filtering)...

Comment: @topchef - Think of a `CURSOR` or `WHILE LOOP` - those are row-by-row operations.

Comment: @Topchef - it is possible to do analysis on individual records

Comment: it's terminology arguments so they are fruitless. I believe you gave exactly the answer sought though.

Answer (score 7):

> I have discussed this with my colleagues, and they also push me to use C++, saying that SQL is not meant for complex analysis but mainly for importing (from the existent tables) and exporting (to new tables) data, and a little bit more such as merging data to - e.g. - joined tables.

This is completely arbitrary. Learn SQL. There are a lot of resources available on the web for free.

Answer (score 5):

You can do very complex analysis of data in SQL, provided you know how use the features that SQL offers.

SQL has features for doing relational operations, like joins and projections.  Also for doing set operations like union, intersection, and restriction (subset).  Also for doing basic arithmetic on numbers,  like the four arithmetic operators, and built in functions like SQRT.  Also statistical functions like COUNT, SUM, and AVG that can be combined with projections in very interesting ways.  A good DBMS will let you extend the built in functions with your own functions written in C, C++ or maybe PL/SQL.

The power you get from these features depends on how well designed the database is.  A well designed database conforms to the relational model, and should be relvant to your intended use of the data.

SQL code can be stored in the database in stored prodecures.  It can be stored in SQL script files.  And, as you already know, it can be embedded in application programs.  In addition to SQL, you can use OLAP tools and report generators to do standard things with the data very easily.

The people who advise you to keep all of your processing in C++ sound like they have learned just enough to use a database like a big and stupid file system.  A good DBMS is much more than that.

Answer (score 4):

SQL is usually very efficient handling its own database (depends on the server implementation).

You should use queries to analyze the database.
The main reason for that would be the communication overhead.
Even if the server is on the local machine (remote servers would have obvious communication overhead), you'll still have to retrieve the stored information from the SQL server to your c++ program for analysis.

Now if you have 10000s of lines in the SQL you would have to get the SQL server to read them all and send them to your program where it would probably create a local copy of the data for you to work on.

If you let the SQL server do it with queries, you'll gain the complex optimizations it does according the kind of query you're executing, and in the end you can retrieve only a limited amount of data (the one you actually need) through the communication.

Answer (score 2):

You made right decision to begin data analysis with SQL. Now, when you feel that your knowledge of SQL limits you,  you have 2 choices: give up and switch back to familiar but not very efficient toolset (C++) or bring your level with SQL up.

It's possible that at some point SQL will become too complex too, but then C++ won't be the answer either - most likely some specialized tools.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should only perform analysis in C++ if no equivalent for the analysis function is provided by database server, As database servers are very smart and it is hard and almost imposible to beat the algorithm efficiency of analysis function of database server. Also bringing raw data to the application for performing analysis also includes lots of overheads.

If at some point plain SQL becomes overly complex native PL of the sever could be a good choice

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JNK and Jochai, but disagree with Ascanio.
It's better to improve the knowledge in database systems.
Sql comes with it

Answer (score 0):

So, this is something I've been thinking about and it seems to me that SQL, as just a platform/language for storing/manipulating data, should have no inherent advantage over a C++ or C library. It seems to me that theoretically you could build a C++ library just as efficient, if not more efficient, than SQL at doing this.  In doing so, you would be able to build it from the ground up, in terms of how ints, chars, strings, and other data types are stored, and make it easier to interface with you particular application (like web development). You could even make it so that the queries could be done in a language like javascript (allowing web developers to focus on just learning one language really well).